Angular 7 to angular 8
I am trying to upgrade my Angular 7 project to Angular 8. I've followed the necessary upgrade steps, including updating packages and configurations. However, when I try to run the project with ng serve, I encounter the following error:
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
TimeoutException: The Angular CLI process did not start listening for requests within the timeout period of 0 seconds. Check the log output for error information.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions.Util.TaskTimeoutExtensions.WithTimeout<T>(Task<T> task, TimeSpan timeoutDelay, string message)

To resolve this issue, I have already tried increasing the StartupTimeout in my startup.cs file:
spa.Options.StartupTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120);

Despite this change, the problem persists.I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue. Thank you!
